# R assignment operators

Tags: r

I was checking R assignment operators and trying to understand how they work, so I wrote the following code:

```
> somevar1 <- "stuff1"
> "stuff2" -> somevar2
> somevar3 = "stuff3"
> "stuff4" <- somevar4
Error: object 'somevar4' not found
> "stuff5" = somevar5
Error: object 'somevar5' not found
> `<-`(somevar6, "stuff6")
> `=`(somevar7, "stuff7")
> `=`("stuff8", somevar8)
Error: object 'somevar8' not found
> `->`("stuff9", somevar9)
Error in `->`("stuff9", somevar9) : could not find function "->"
> `<<-`(somevar10, "stuff10")
> `->>`("stuff11", somevar11)
Error in `->>`("stuff11", somevar11) : could not find function "->>"
```

Up to the line, where `somevar9` is being used, everything seems in line with expectations.
However, I don't get why I'm getting the errors like `Error in` ->`("stuff9", somevar9) : could not find function "->"` and `Error in` ->>`("stuff11", somevar11) : could not find function "->>"`. Should they not exist for the `->` and `->>` operators to work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think when the R parser comes across `a -> b` it calls `'<-'("b", a)` and when it comes across `a ->> b` it calls `'<<-'("b", a)`.

Comment: Yeah, I am not an expert so won't answer, but backing up what @Allan Cameron put, you can see the existence of these functions by typing `<-` and `<<-` and the opposite trying `->` `->>`.

Comment: [Colin Fay](https://colinfay.me/r-assignment/)'s article provides some interesting follow-up questions about legacy operators `:=` and `_`. For example, `%%`-less infix operators are possible. Also worth to have a look at their [precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html)

Comment: `x = y <- 15` - I did not know you could do this! Thanks a lot for sharing the article @DonaldSeinen!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the R parser comes across `a -> b` it calls `'<-'("b", a)` and when it comes across `a ->> b` it calls `'<<-'("b", a)`

We can see this explicitly if we do the following:

```r
as.call(quote(a <- 1))
#> a <- 1
as.call(quote(a <<- 1))
#> a <<- 1
as.call(quote(1 -> a))
#> a <- 1
as.call(quote(1 ->> a))
#> a <<- 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Nice thanks! Makes sense.
I think the `expr` function is a part of `rlang` package, so I checked it with `bquote` like this:
`as.call(bquote(a ->> 1))`

Comment: @abudis you're right. I've changed it to base R's `quote`